# Why does CardView background color change?

Tags: java, android, xml

I've created a CardView with the background color red. On new devices it shows a red circle, but on older devices for example my virtual device, it shows a transparent circler with a shadow.

Now I'm curious how it's possible that the circle goes transparent on some devices and on some not?

This is the cardView part of activity_main.xml

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/notification_circle"
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/red"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="50dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/notiButton"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/notiButton">


                    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/notification_number"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


                    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The result should be this:
[image: Should be]

But this is the actual result:
[image: The actual result]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say "older devices" what android versions are we talking about

Comment: My virtual device has the API Level 24

Comment: I would recommend putting a linear layout in the cardView and changing the color of the linear layout. That should solve the problem

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help